# Show that $f$ is surjective

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ continuous, such that $|f(x)-f(y)| \geq \frac{1}{2}|x-y|$, for all $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$.

It is one one obvious, so it is monotonic, it seems it has to be onto but ca not formalize the proof.

Comment: Since you know it is monotonic, you can presume it is increasing (apply to $-f$ if not). Then by choosing $y=0$, for example, you can show that $f(x) \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Combine monotonicity with the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that no value can be missed.